# Is there any civil aircraft that decelerates with a parachute?

Tags: landing, parachute

Some previous generations military aircraft decelerate with a parachute to decrease landing distance:

[image]
<sup>Israel Aircraft Industries Kfir landing with a parachute ([source](http://www.avionslegendaires.net/2013/11/actu/photo-kfir-a-latterrissage-parachute-ouvert/))</sup>

It this something found on any civil aircraft today?

Comment: Generally speaking, I thought all aircraft decelerated with the deployment of a parachute.  (grin)  Whether military, civilian or experimental.

Comment: I assume you don’t include gliders?

Comment: This has actually been asked before; See https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24530/do-any-commercial-airline-models-have-a-parachute-at-rear-to-help-in-landings

Comment: @Penguin: Good find, let's close this as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
[image]
(airliners.net)

Some early civilian jets had drogue parachutes such as the [Caravelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Aviation_Caravelle) and the [Tupolev Tu-104](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-104).

While the [reverse systems](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/43569/14897) are heavier than the [parachutes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/43590/14897), they are more practical (no stowing and [running after](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30392/why-is-the-drogue-parachute-jettisoned-on-the-runway) rogue parachutes).

Regarding the edit for today's planes: they went out of fashion for the civilian jets.

- For newly built jets, there aren't any as far as I know. Older jets that may still be airworthy, and military aircraft that may have been converted to civilian use, are not included in my assessment.

The weight saving makes sense for fighters which are range limited due to the high performance engines and the placement (and type) of the nozzle. The weight of a reverse system is better substituted with fuel or ordnance. The [Saab 37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saab_37_Viggen) does have reverse though.

[image]
([Source](http://www.ainonline.com/sites/default/files/styles/ain30_fullwidth_large_2x/public/uploads/2015/09/g500spinchute.jpg?itok=3caJ27Kz&timestamp=1441804619)) Parachute used for an [attitude recovery system](http://www.gulfstream.com/gulfstreamnow/article/gn-attitude-recovery-system-installed-for-g500-flight-testing). It's not meant for decelerating though.

[image]
([Twitter](https://twitter.com/ianjkeddie/status/872504998671908864)) Norwegian F-35's will also have parachute brakes (related to the note on fighter generations).

---

Related and/or duplicate, you decide: [Do any commercial airline models have a parachute at rear to help in landings?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24530/14897) (Answers are more thorough and include gliders.)

Comment: It seems your answer is "There is no parachute for landing on civil aircraft at the present time." Is that correct?

Comment: It’s very difficult to land ON any type of aircraft, military or civilian, with or without a parachute. Even a gigantic aircraft is just too small a surface to land on.